# Programmatically translating recurring calendar events?

Tags: internationalization, machine-translation, recurring-events, rrule

Does anyone know of a solution or strategy for parsing and translating recurring events in any given language?

I've got some code that sort of works, but I'm having trouble even wrapping my brain around a solid approach.

Answer (score 0):

By "parse" you mean free-form text in **any** language?

That is nearly impossible to do. The problem is, you can describe that in many ways (even in English, right?). Put [inflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) in the picture and...
You would need some kind of cognitive system, that is you would need to employ machine learning. Theoretically speaking you'll be interested in only few [ontologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) but getting translated versions of them might not be too easy (I have seen a presentation of such web service but I believe it was more academic work and the service is not publicly available).

Taking these facts into account, I can suggest (unless you really must parse free form text, i.e. sent via email or something) that you create a form where people can actually choose recurring frequency and options (i.e. ignore holidays, etc.). It is still uneasy task but...

Comment: Ah! No, 'parse' was completely the wrong word to use. I meant to say outputting structured data for recurring events (rrules) in translated language. I'll update my question.

Comment: Actually, I've just made a better question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605302/internationalizing-recurring-calendar-event-descriptions

Answer (score 0):

There are various libraries which can parse RRULE's in several languages.

### RRULE Libraries

C          - [libical](https://github.com/Marketcircle/libical) 
Python     - [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) 
Ruby       - [ice_cube](https://github.com/digITpro/ice_cube) 
Javascript - [google-caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/rrule-cajita.js?r=4000) or [rrule](https://github.com/jkbr/rrule) 
Java       - [iCal4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page) 
PHP        - [when](https://github.com/tplaner/When)

As for strategies, take a look at the standard [here](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html) which provides architectural pseudo-code for abstracting rrule data.